# RabbitMQ localhost strange character text

Tags: debian, rabbitmq, vagrant, puppet

I have installed rabbitmq 3.5.3 via puppet in a vagrant machine running debian 7.6.

Now it all seems to go very well, but now when I go to http://localhost:5672/ I only see this:

> AMQP��

I now its running. Vagrant/Puppet aren't giving me any errors.

What is missing??

Comment: What do you expect to see at  http://localhost:5672/?

Answer (score 2):

The 5672 is the port used for connection using the AMQP protocol.

If you want to connect to the rabbitmq management ui, it listens (by default) on [the 15672 port](http://localhost:15672/)